# Find amount of days between 2 dates in php

Tags: php, date

I have 2 dates and want to know how many the amount of days that come between them.

Lets say these two are the dates

> 2015-11-16 10:01:13
>   2015-05-06 09:47:16

The first one being right now, how can I calculate how many days are in between the two given dates?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Try having a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php), the DateInterval object helps for this kind of thing :)

Comment: Does my comment & answer help at all?

Comment: I have amended my question to include your *exact* dates, please see the amends and let me know if it helps :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. It is very simple.

```
    <?php

     $date1 = strtotime("2015-11-16 10:01:13");
     $date2 = strtotime("2015-05-06 09:47:16");
     $datediff = $date1 - $date2;
     echo floor($datediff/(60*60*24))." days"; //output 194 days

    ?>
```

Comment: I think this is a great solution, but more complex that it is needing to be, I think (IMO), the best solution to use is the DateTime and DateInterval API provided by PHP, they make quick and light work of the conversion you are doing, for example, `strtotime` - done by `new DateTime('string')`  and `echo(floor($datediff/(60*60*24)) . " days";` - done by `echo $interval->format('%R%a days');`, to me the OOP/Procedural style of the Date API is much better :)

Comment: Works fine, thanks! I'ma look into the strtotime function too

Answer (score 4):

Following my comment, I thought I would post some examples from the PHP.net [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php):

OOP style:

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
```

Procedural style:

```
<?php
$datetime1 = date_create('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = date_create('2009-10-13');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
```

Both examples will output:

> **+2 days**

You can also compare word strings as such (when using OOP style, this is an example from PHP.net):

```
<?php
$date1 = new DateTime("now");
$date2 = new DateTime("tomorrow");
var_dump($date1 == $date2);
var_dump($date1 < $date2);
var_dump($date1 > $date2);
?>
```

Producing:

> bool(false)
>      bool(true)
>      bool(false)

Using your dates:

OOP

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2015-11-16 10:01:13');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2015-05-06 09:47:16');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
```

Procedural

```
<?php
$datetime1 = date_create('2015-11-16 10:01:13');
$datetime2 = date_create('2015-05-06 09:47:16');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
```

Result from both:

> -194 days

I sincerely hope this helps :)

Comment: Is there a way of doing it without the "->"?

Comment: The `->` is a standard PHP *thing*, to do without is almost like saying, *I'm using PHP, but I don't want to use PHP syntax*...

Comment: The `date_create` and `new DateTime()` both create an object of DateTimeInterface, so to use without the `->` syntax is impossible in this case, but it is one of the cleanest ways to do it that's not going to give complex and convoluted results in the code (i.e. Amit's answer with the manual conversion to days, it's complex and slower than it needs to be)

Comment: It is the same amount of lines of code as Amit's answer, but it is faster and a lot more readable than Amit's, if someone gave me the code `echo floor($datediff/(60*60*24));`, I for one wouldn't know what it was! :-)

Comment: I've wrote thousands of lines of php without it :P

Comment: Thats because it is an OOP thing, when you use classes, you will **HAVE** to use th `->` syntax, it's rather powerful as things go, and I agree, I've written millions of lines without, but none more pwerful that 2 with OOP `->` syntax :P