# Jump to top of page on form submit to new page

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a form on a PHP page :

```
<form name="SendEmail01" method="post">
    form items here...
</form>
```

I then process it like this:

```
if(isset($_POST["Submit"]))
{
All tasks here...
$thanks_redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . '/thanks.php#top';
header("location: $thanks_redirect");
}
```

The issue is that the submit button on the processing page is quite low down on the page and when I press 'Submit' it all processes correctly and jumps to the thanks.php page correctly, but the page stays in the same location and it looks like its just a blank page (unless the user scrolls up).

I have tried Javascript and HTML hyperlinks such as #top but it will just not jump back to the top of the page where, on the thanks.php page, it says that it has all been processed correctly.

Could anyone please help with how I get the thanks.php page to scroll back to the top of the page once the form has been processed?

Edit : I have this on the thanks.php page where the user is redirected on submission:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var lockit=setInterval("window.scrollTo(0,0)",10)
</script>
<style>
form {
    display: inline;
}
input
{
color: #000000;
background: #ffffff;
border: 1px solid #000000;
padding: 4px;
font-size:13px;
font 
}
#submit {
 color: #000000;
 font-size: 13px;
 width: 110px;
 height: 30px;
 border: 1px solid #000000;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background: #66ff66 url(image) 0 0 no-repeat; 
}
#buttons {
 color: #000000;
 font-size: 13px;
 width: 80px;
 height: 25px;
 border: 1px solid #000000;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background: #66ff66 url(image) 0 0 no-repeat; 
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');
</script>
<?php
session_start();
$loggedin_user = $_SESSION['serial'];
$local_path = $_SESSION['local_path'];
$full_path = $_SESSION['full_path'];
?>
<font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="black">

<form action="http://<?php echo $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]; ?>/login.php?log_out">
    <input type="submit" value="Logout" id="buttons">
</form>
<form action="<?php echo $full_path;?>index.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Go Back" id="buttons">
</form>
<p><b>Success!</p></b>
<p>Your changes have been submitted.. 

<p>Please note that not <u>all</u> changes are made in real-time, some changes may only be updated when the server checks for new configuration.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Submit fully sends data so surely you do not need the `#top` in the uri, just let it do it's thang :)

Comment: As mentioned by Sam, it should show at the top anyway, if it isn't, then I suspect there's something wrong with the HTML markup on your thanks.php page.

Comment: You don't need to do anything in order to reach to the top. Just redirect to any page and it will always show the top.

Comment: Is there any input box or jquery code in thanks.php page which is focusing to that input box?

Comment: Thanks all, it doesn't jump to the top, it just sits at the same height on the new page.

Comment: @omega1, is there any CSS making the page jump down somewhat? (No idea how this is done in CSS mind!)

Comment: Change `<body onLoad=”clearInterval(lockit)”>` to `<body onLoad="clearInterval(lockit)">`

Comment: @Sam Swift No, I have just taken all CSS out and it has the same effect. P.S.s It is the same behaviour across all browsers and OS's

Comment: What a strange issue, do you have any custom jQuery/JavaScript/Java that has a `focus` event attached to it somewhere on the thanks.php page?

Comment: @Akshay Nicely spotted, but it still didn't work

Comment: Try to remove the onLoad event from the body tags, see if thats causing the ish, if not then it can always go back in again :)

Comment: replace this <body onLoad=”clearInterval(lockit)”> with <body onLoad="clearInterval(lockit)"> and check again

Comment: Or expand on Amit's answer and use `<body onload="return clearInterval(lockit);">` (we don't use camelCase in the onload call for any HTML attrib tags :) )

Comment: if you have an `<a>` somewhere near the top of your page try `document.querySelect("#blah").focus()` method with javascript

Comment: you need to post your full code for thanks.php and make sure you've loaded the jQuery library, because that's what that syntax is. Btw, it's javascript and not Java; 2 different animals.

Comment: also, PHP does NOT recognize hashtags `/thanks.php#top` so you need to remove that.

Comment: @Fred-ii-,  though that a URI did support the hashes? For example, my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33732686/find-amount-of-days-between-2-dates-in-php/33732753#33732753) is scrolled to with the `#...` but not without?

Comment: @SamSwift PHP is PHP, any way you slice it and it does not support hashtags. OP was asked to post their full code, and either don't want to or they ran off. So, I won't be providing further help on the question. Good luck with your answer ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-, that sounds fair to me! I'll get-a-huntin'!

Comment: I have no idea as to why this question was upvoted so much.

Comment: @Fred This place can be quite harsh sometimes. I have no issue with posting my code, nor had I ran away. I have updated my original question with the full code of thanks.php which is where the user is redirected. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add this as a comment, but it's a bit too long for it.

I made this page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

    <p>Calibri Text</p>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <form>
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

On submission, the page jumps to the top along with a redirect to another page, so you shouldn't be having this issue less there is something in your jQuery giving something focus.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');
```

You don't need any `custom divs` for this. Just have a simple page.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Thanks Page</title>
</head>
<body>

Well Thanks bro!

</body>
</html>
```