# How can I calculate the difference between these two dates using R?

Tags: r, difftime

I have a data set which containing 2 columns with dates with the following formats:

```
"2027-02-20 00:00:00 CET"    and "2014-12-31 CET"
```

how can I calculate the difference between these two dates? Or, how can I apply `difftime` ?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14454476/get-the-difference-between-dates-in-terms-of-weeks-months-quarters-and-years) is a useful discussion but I cannot apply it directly?!

I gave by myself the link (above see: Here is blue) where one can find a very similar problem but not exact the same. Unfortunately some of people do not read the question carefully. Just one gave a useful hint. One dose not need any string manipulation!

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I guess I have to apply string manipulation at first! I am still working on it

Comment: @Pascal did you check the link which I mentioned?!

Comment: Read `help("strptime")`. No string manipulation is required to parse datetimes.

Comment: You could also search: place `[r] parse date` or `[r] strptime` in the search box above.

Comment: Having read the link you provided you should be able to solve your problem as everything is explained in the answers.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33732686/find-amount-of-days-between-2-dates-in-php/33732753?noredirect=1#comment55241148_33732753)

Comment: Oh thanks  @SamSwift  I did not check it unfortunately but anyway thanks!

Comment: @maniA, I must apologise for a mistake on my part, the question I tagged was for PHP where yours is R, please ignore that comment! Apologies again!

Comment: @SamSwift better than some aggressive comments ;) no worries and thanks for your time anyway!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the difference between dates in terms of weeks, months, quarters, and years](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14454476/get-the-difference-between-dates-in-terms-of-weeks-months-quarters-and-years)

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem, the hint of Roland was really useful. I did not really need any string manipulation. If I apply

```
difftime(strptime("2027-02-20 00:00:00 CET", format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
         strptime("2014-12-31 CET", format = "%Y-%m-%d"),units="weeks")
```

it works well.