# PHP - Count number of days between 2 dates

Tags: php, date, count

I am trying to write a function that can count the number of days between 2 dates. I currently have the below but it is giving me some unexpected results:

```
function dayCount($from, $to) {
    $first_date = strtotime($from);
    $second_date = strtotime($to);
    $offset = $second_date-$first_date; 
    return floor($offset/60/60/24);
}

print dayCount($s, $e).' Days';
```

A couple of correct examples:

```
$s = '18-03-2016';
$e = '25-03-2016';
```

Outputs: `7 Days` - **correct**

```
$s = '03-02-2016';
$e = '06-02-2016';
```

Outputs: `3 Days` - **correct**

```
$s = '06-04-2016';
$e = '27-04-2016';
```

Outputs: `21 Days` - **correct**

But when I have dates that cross over between 2 months sometimes it is correct, sometimes it shows a day less:

```
$s = '25-03-2016';
$e = '01-04-2016';
```

Outputs: `6 Days` - **should be 7 Days**

```
$s = '23-02-2016';
$e = '01-03-2016';
```

Outputs: `7 Days` - **correct**

Comment: Why not use `date_diff` PHP function?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33732686/find-amount-of-days-between-2-dates-in-php/33732864#33732864

Comment: It's not the "cross over between 2 months" that's causing the issue. The issue is intervals starting on or before '27-03-2016' and ending on or after '28-03-2016'. March 27, 2016 is the start of Daylight Saving Time (in the EU). When calculating a difference in seconds between two timestamps, from strings with different timezone offsets... in a timezone that observes DST, there's only 23 hours in March 27, 2016.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please use `diff` function for get days between two date.

```
$date1 = new DateTime("25-03-2016");
$date2 = new DateTime("01-04-2016");

echo $diff = $date2->diff($date1)->format("%a");
```

Answer (score 6):

please use date_diff function like this

```
<?php
$date1=date_create("2013-03-15");
$date2=date_create("2013-12-12");
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
echo $diff->format("%R%a days");
?>
```

hope this helps you thanx.

Comment: Plus one for taking negative numbers in to account

Answer (score 3):

You can also use this (for versions PHP 5.1.5 and above without using date_diff()):

```
function dayCount($from, $to) {
    $first_date = strtotime($from);
    $second_date = strtotime($to);
    $days_diff = $second_date - $first_date;
    return date('d',$days_diff);
}

print dayCount($s, $e).' Days';
```

Comment: No leading 0     return date('j',$days_diff);